# How to hold old value in selectlist after clicking on Save button

Tags: visualforce

I have a VF page in which I have created a picklist using SelectList and SelectOption. I am now facing final hurdle: Selected value is getting changed to default one once I click on Save . I am not sure how should I code so that the value of SelectList doesn't revert back to default one and remain the selected one when I click on Save.

This is some part of my VF page:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Technical Approval" id="techapprovalsection" >
         <apex:pageBlock> 
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
               <apex:outputLabel value="Technical Approver 1"></apex:outputLabel>
               <apex:selectList multiselect="false" required="true" value="{!TechnicalApprover1}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!TechnicalAppList}"/>
               </apex:selectList>
             </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
           </apex:pageBlock>

         <apex:pageBlock >
           <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
             <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!dosave}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         </apex:pageBlock>
```

Below is some portion of my Controller class:

```
public class SubmitforApprovalController {
public SubmitforApprovalController() {
searchTechApproval(OfferType, SalesPrice, MOMargin, objMO);
}

public List<SelectOption> searchTechApproval(String OfferType, Decimal SalesPrice, Decimal MOMargin, Custom1__c objMO)
{
 QueriedTechApprovers= [Select Id, Name, Approval_Level__c, GID__c, Mail__c, Offer_Type__c, 
                        SalesPrice_Range__c, Signature__c, TotalMargin_Range__c,
                        Max_Stages__c, Stage__c, First_Name__c, Last_Name__c from Approver__c 
                        Where Sales_Volume_LB__c <= :TotalPrice AND Sales_Volume_UB__c > :TotalPrice];
if(QueriedTechApprovers.size()>0){
            TechnicalApprover1 = QueriedTechApprovers[0].Name;

if(QueriedSalesApprovers.size()>0){
        for(Approver__c app : QueriedSalesApprovers){
          lstSalesApprovers.add(new SelectOption (app.Name,app.Name));
 }
}

public pageReference dosave(){
if(!String.isEmpty(TechnicalApprover1) && QueriedTechApprovers.size()>0){
       Approver__c TechApproverChange1 = [Select Id, Name, Stage__c,First_Name__c, Last_Name__c from Approver__c WHERE ID =: TechIDs AND Name =: TechnicalApprover1 LIMIT 1];
        Approval__c apptech1 = new Approval__c();
        apptech1.Main_Offer_Name__c = objMO.Id;
        apptech1.Approver_Name__c = TechApproverChange1.Id;
        apptech1.Stage__c = TechApproverChange1.Stage__c;
        insert apptech1;
        isTechApprover = true;
     }
```

Whenever I click on Save button, page refreshes and value of picklist changes to default one set by controller. I want it to remain as it is.

Comment: Please do not repost closed questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you have a String variable named `TechnicalApprover1` with a getter/setter. Since there is no rerender attribute in your command button, the page refreshes.

Step 1: Add an `id` to one of the `pageBlock` and rerender that id in `commandbutton`.

```
 <apex:pageBlock id="selectlist">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:outputLabel value="Technical Approver 1"></apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:selectList multiselect="false" required="true" value="{!TechnicalApprover1}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!TechnicalAppList}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!dosave}" rerender="selectlist"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Also, in the save method return null. I think you are doing that already but is is not visible in your code.

```
public pageReference dosave(){

// Your code
return null;
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but it still refreshed the pageblock which in turn calls the method searchTechApproval and again default value for TechnicalApprover1 is set when I click on Save.

Comment: Then you should keep a check in your code which only sets the value for `TechnicalApprover1` if it is not blank. You can do it where you are setting the value `TechnicalApprover1 =  QueriedTechApprovers[0].Name;` put this inside an `if`.

Comment: That was such a simple yet effective solution. How did I not think of this? Thanks a lot for you help Manjit and stay Safe.